# keras add features after embedding

Tags: machine-learning, keras, nlp, embedding, part-of-speech

I want to add part of speech features into my word vector after embedding in Keras. I would like to add them as one hot and concat them after embedding. But the part of speech of a word is dynamic so I can't use another embedding layer for part of speech one hot look up and combine two embedding layers.

Comment: Do you have POS feature as input?

Comment: No. But I will generate POS feature using some packages.

Comment: so in your case you have feature x and you need [x, x1] where x1 = f(x). This can be done as preprocessing step, before feeding to model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple approach, I'm assuming input as a word and its POS tag.

```
word = Input(...)
pos = Input(...)
emb = Embedding( ... ) (word)
layer = Concatenate()([emb, pos])
outputs = .... # your processing
model = Model(inputs=[word,pos], outputs=outputs)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll give it a try.

Comment: @sathyz can you please explain where the `layer` variable is used?

Comment: Refer [Keras functional API](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/). In this case, you could just do `outputs = Dense(10, activation="softmax") (layer)`

Answer (score 0):

SathyZ just want to know we dont have to use embedding layer for pos tag

```
word = Input(...)
pos = Input(...)
emb_word = Embedding( ... ) (word)
emb_pos = Embedding( ... ) (pos)
layer = Concatenate()([emb, pos])
outputs = .... # your processing
model = Model(inputs=[word,pos], outputs=outputs)
```